# Lightning Component Vs Visualforce Page in AppExchange Product

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, appexchange, salesforce-classic

I am creating a small free application for AppExchange. As many of the Salesforce customers are still using Classic Interface, I want to develop this application which will be compatible with Classic and Lightning.

For implementation, below are two development approaches :

- Crete full application in Lightning Component and Embed Lightning Components in Visualforce page for Classic Users by using Lightning out (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm)
- Create a full application in Visualforce page + LDSC and make it available in Lightning.

Can someone please suggest, which approach would be better from AppExchange Architecture perspective?

Thanks,

Ashish

Comment: I will go for vfpage route because there are many thing not supported in Lightning out if your end customer are using classic and lightning both.